# Unity 3D C# Levels lock & unlock

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a 3D game with Unity and C# and i don't know how to make a level menu with locked levels and unlock system.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgRqW.jpg

SelectLevel.cs (The menu with levels) :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class SelectLevel : MonoBehaviour
{

  public void selectLevel()
  {
    switch (this.gameObject.name) {
      case "Level01" :
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Level01");
      break;

      case "Level02" :
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Level02");
      break;

    }
  }

}
```

LevelComplete.cs :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelComplete : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void LoadNextLevel ()
    {

      SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: when do you want the levels to unlock ? if its after finishing the previous level you can use playerprefs to save a variable in a file to know which level have been complreted or not.

Comment: Yes,  it's after finishing the previous level. Can you give me more details or an code example ?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use the interactable feature with the Buttons. So have some manager that tracks when a level is completed/unlocked, and based on that set the Button to either be interactable or not. You can find a similar question with code [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/981517/how-to-enabledisable-ui-buttons.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the next level to unlock after the completion of the previous level you should make an array of all the levels in the game and mark each one as completed when they are finished. Based on that you can take the next level in the array and "unlock" it.

pseudo code:

```
        int[] levels = new int[15];                     // 15 levels in existance

        if (level1completed == true)
        {
            levels[0] = 1;                              // set the valua to 1 if it has been completed
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level1", levels[0]);    // make a file called "level1" and give it a value of levels[0]
        }
```

now where you have the code to load the level on click you should use an
if statement to check if the previous level was completed

```
  if (buttonlevel2clicked == true)
        {
            levels[0] =  PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level1", 0); // retreive the int from the file and assign it to variable

            if (levels[0] == 1) //checks if level 1 has been completed 
            {
                level2.load(); //loads level 2
            }
        }
```

This code could be improved by not hard coding the level loading but this should give you an idea of what to do (i haven't tested it)

Playerprefs >> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: Storing in PlayerPrefs will allow people to modify the storage where PlayerPrefs are stored and bypass levels.

Comment: if people want to cheat they will find a way, in any case, unless its a multiplayer game, why restrict the user's freedom ?

Comment: If this is an app that generates revenue by in-app purchases that help the user advance to the next level then that would be why you restrict the user's freedom and try to prevent cheating as much as possible.

Comment: I tried to give a simple answer that worked for me based on the question asked, with all due respect, I don't believe that somebody asking how to make a level manager is about to be implementing micro transactions and other anti cheat protocols.

Comment: Then at the same time this answer is setting up the poster (and other readers of the post & answer) for future failure for when he does add micro transactions and anti cheat protocols to this or some other app by giving the impression that PlayerPrefs is the best place to store sensitive information like how to skip locked levels without playing the appropriate levels first.

Comment: thank you for your input, i would love if you posted an answer showing the correct way to store this kind of data.

Comment: What i had was pseudo code, you need to adapt the variables to your situation, you should activate the boolean level1completed after the user has entered the end zone of the level. buttonlevel2clicked should be activated before you try to load level 2 to check if level 1 has been completed.